# Pandas bug on pivot_table with dict aggfunc?

Tags: python, pandas

No problem with this sample of pivot_table with dict aggfunc:

```
df=pandas.DataFrame([
    {'JOB':'Worker','NAME':'Bob' ,'YEAR':2013,'MONTH':12,'DAYS': 3,'SALARY': 17},
    {'JOB':'Employ','NAME':'Mary','YEAR':2013,'MONTH':12,'DAYS': 5,'SALARY': 23},
    {'JOB':'Worker','NAME':'Bob' ,'YEAR':2014,'MONTH': 1,'DAYS':10,'SALARY':100},
    {'JOB':'Worker','NAME':'Bob' ,'YEAR':2014,'MONTH': 1,'DAYS':11,'SALARY':110},
    {'JOB':'Employ','NAME':'Mary','YEAR':2014,'MONTH': 1,'DAYS':15,'SALARY':200},
    {'JOB':'Worker','NAME':'Bob' ,'YEAR':2014,'MONTH': 2,'DAYS': 8,'SALARY': 80},
    {'JOB':'Employ','NAME':'Mary','YEAR':2014,'MONTH': 2,'DAYS': 5,'SALARY':190}
    ])

df=df.set_index(['JOB','NAME','YEAR','MONTH'],drop=False,append=False)

df=df.pivot_table(index=['JOB','NAME'],columns=['YEAR','MONTH'],values=['DAYS','SALARY'],aggfunc={'DAYS':'mean','SALARY':'sum'})
```

But using margins pandas raise a key error:

```
df=df.pivot_table(index=['JOB','NAME'],columns=['YEAR','MONTH'],values=['DAYS','SALARY'],aggfunc={'DAYS':'mean','SALARY':'sum'},margins=True)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.14.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/util/decorators.py", line 60, in wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.14.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/util/decorators.py", line 60, in wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.14.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/tools/pivot.py", line 147, in pivot_table
cols=columns, aggfunc=aggfunc)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.14.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/tools/pivot.py", line 191, in _add_margins
row_margin[k] = grand_margin[k[0]]

KeyError: 'SALARY'
```

Is it a bug?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It is a fixed bug : based on  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/release.html :

Fixed ([GH3334](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3334)) in pivot_table. Margins did not compute if values is the index.

Comment: I think it is another problem, anyway I use the last release and it raise the error.

Comment: as i say it is a fixed error ! and your error is because of your value is the index !

Comment: Sorry but my values are not in the index.

Comment: what do you changed ?

Comment: sorry im confused ! i haven't any idea ! now!

Comment: Could you please delete your answer? Thank